# How to load geotiff data as 3D terrain in CesiumJs from Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, cesiumjs

Can someone provide me a step by step guidance on how to load geotiff data as 3D terrain in CesiumJs from Geoserver?

I was able to load as geotiff data as 'image/png' but don't know how to laod it as 3D with all elevation.

```
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer',{
    animation : false,
});
viewer.imageryLayers.remove(viewer.imageryLayers.get(0));
viewer.timeline.container.style.display="none";
viewer.bottomContainer.style.display = "NONE"; //capitalized

 var url = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cesium/wms'; //Geoserver URL
    var provider1 = new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
        url : url,
     layers:'cesium:geotiff',//layer name
        parameters: {
            service: 'WMS',
            format: 'image/png',
            transparent: true,
        }
});
viewer.imageryLayers.addImageryProvider(provider1);
```

Comment: You are creating an imagery layer, not the terrain. Please use the following awesome project.

https://github.com/kaktus40/Cesium-GeoserverTerrainProvider

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you. It worked but I'm Getting sharp edges.